# The phenomenon where a model created in Blender does not load in VroidMobile

Tags: workflow, conversion, external-applications

You've successfully converted a model created in Blender to a VRM file and uploaded it to VroidHub. However, the model isn't displaying in VroidMobile on your smartphone.
[image]

VroidHub and VroidMobile accounts are linked, and you've set it to "Only Me" for use.

VroidHub→https://hub.vroid.com/
VroidMobile→https://vroid.com/mobile

I want to add this link to VroidMobile in advance.
[image]

I'm using ChatGPT to translate into English.

Comment: Welcome to BSE. What have you used to convert to VRM? This is probably their problem, not Blender's

Comment: The approach to try is to cut the model in half, and see if either half works upon exporting. If not, continue cutting until you end up with a single triangle. If that triangle still doesn't show, cut something else than geometry - start removing materials, and whatever other attributes there are. This strategy should eventually succeed in finding the element that fails to export...

Comment: @RobinBetts
I used the following add-on to convert it to VRM.
[link](https://vrm-addon-for-blender.info/en/)